# Странный приоритет выполнения операций, приведение типов данных

Tags: java

В Java высший приоритет выполнения имеют операции заключенные в скобки. Здесь tip1=2.4 а tip2=0.0 хотя должен быть равен tip1.

```
double mealCost = 12;
int tipPercent = 20;

double tip1 =  mealCost*tipPercent/100;
double tip2 =  mealCost*(tipPercent/100);

System.out.println(tip1);
System.out.println(tip2);
```

Comment: и в чем вопрос? почему результаты различаются? или почему именно такие результаты получаются? или еще что?

Comment: Ну все верно. Вы делите int на int и получаете дробное число..... он приводит к этому типу и получает ноль в результате деления........ чтоб такого не было надо как минимум написать `tipPercent/(double)100` ну или `tipPercent/(float)100`..... в зависимости от того, какую точность хотите получить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы хотели написать "int на int и получаете целое число".

Comment: @Russtam нет, я просто неправильно выразился.....надо было написать, что в результате деления данных целых чисел (которые в скобках) получается дробное число, а не упоминать int на int)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в результате деления данных целых чисел в скобках получается не дробное число, а целое. Так что вы оба раза неправильно "выразились" ;)

Comment: @Russtam ну да наверное) 20/100 будет 0.2 и потом т.к. нет приведения к типу все приводится к int, т.е к 0..... мне так надо было написать? )) видимо из-за этого я и не стал ответ писать))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да нет, даже 0.2 не будет, оба операнда int, и никаких преобразований к float или double не будет, просто делится целое на целое, без вычисления дробной части.

Comment: @Russtam ну ок) запомню)  но смысл один фиг был в том, что без приведения типа операция дает ноль и нужно явно указать тип

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Деление целых чисел дает целый результат

```
double mealCost = 12;
int tipPercent = 20;

double tip1 =  mealCost*tipPercent/100; //первый операнд double, далее все вычисляется именно в double
double tip2 =  mealCost*(tipPercent/100); //первый и второй операнды скобок int, деление целочисленное
double tip2 =  mealCost*(tipPercent/100.); //первый операнд скобок int, но второй double, поэтому деление происходит в double
double tip2 =  mealCost*((double)tipPercent/100); //или так
System.out.println(tip1);
System.out.println(tip2);
```